# Парсинг даты и её преобразование | Kotlin | Date

Tags: kotlin, дата

Парсю сайт и нужно сделать следующее:

1. Получить дату в виде строки
2. Преобразовать строку во временную метку
3. Получить разницу между текущем временем и меткой
4. Преобразовать результат в строку

Ничего сложного нет, за исключение даты, которую я получаю. Вот немного логов:

```
I/PARSER: 29 марта 2020 г., 20:27
I/PARSER: 06 авг. 2019 г., 0:27
I/PARSER: 06 авг. 2019 г., 0:27
I/PARSER: 06 авг. 2019 г., 0:28
I/PARSER: 22 нояб. 2019 г., 11:16
```

А парсить строку я пытаюсь так:

```
val s = "29 марта 2020 г., 20:27"
val format = SimpleDateFormat()
format.applyPattern("d b Y г., R")
val docDate: Date = format.parse(s)
```

Проблема в том, что месяц иногда с точкой, а иногда нет. Как мне правильно спарсить подобную дату?

Правка 1: Подправил паттерн и теперь он правильный, но вопрос остается.

```
d MMM. Y., HH:mm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны описать каждый возможный формат вашей даты. После чего вы можете попробовать что-то вроде такого:

```
// ...
val formatStrings: List<String> = listOf("d MMM. Y., HH:mm", "d MMMM Y., HH:mm")
// ...

fun tryParse(dateString: String): Date {
    for (formatString in formatStrings) {
        try {
            return SimpleDateFormat(formatString).parse(dateString)
        }
        catch (e: ParseException) {}
    }

    return null
}
```